# How to write by.cssContainingText() in chrome console?

Tags: console, protractor

I have to write by.cssContainingText() in chrome console .This is regarding protractor.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the implement of `by.cssContainingText(cssSelector, searchText)`, it does two steps:

1. run `querySelectorAll(cssSelector)` to get a element list
2. iterate the element list to find which one's text match the `searchText`

Following is implement code of `cssContainingText()`, you also can find it at [github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L686)

```
functions.findByCssContainingText = function(cssSelector, searchText, using) {
  using = using || document;

  if (searchText.indexOf('__REGEXP__') === 0) {
    var match = searchText.split('__REGEXP__')[1].match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)?/);
    searchText = new RegExp(match[1], match[2] || '');
  }
  var elements = using.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
  var matches = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var elementText = element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
    var elementMatches = searchText instanceof RegExp ?
        searchText.test(elementText) :
        elementText.indexOf(searchText) > -1;

    if (elementMatches) {
      matches.push(element);
    }
  }
  return matches;
};
```

It's more complex to write equivalent in browser's console, but you can do as following:

1. Open stackoverflow site: https://stackoverflow.com/
2. execute following example code in browser console
3. expand the return result in console
4. mouse over on each item of return result in console, then you can notice the mouse will over on the corresponding element on page as following screenshot

Example code:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li > a')).filter((it)=>{return (it.textContent || it.innerText || '').contains('Users')})
```

Screenshot of example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good way to approach it lets see the syntax

```
<ul>
  <li class="pet">Dog</li>
  <li class="pet">Cat</li>
</ul>

// Returns the li for the dog, but not cat.

var dog = element(by.cssContainingText('.pet', 'Dog'));
```

inside the bracket the first argument is the .classname and the second argument is the actual text .Better write it in script and check it .it'll work